# Having issue regarding to checklistbox

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a checkedListBox and a TextBox...When I Checked item in the checkedListBox it shows the value of the respective item in the TextBox...When I Checked multiple items in the checkedListBox it shows the values of the respective items in the TextBox separating by {,}"Comma"

Now my question is that when I unchecked the item in the textBox it must remove the value of respective unchecked items from the textBox ...also please tell me how do I remove "Comma"{,} from the end of the text box programmatically

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=email_client;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * FROM address_book ", connection);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            {
                SqlDataReader drd = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (drd.Read())
                {
                    this.checkedListBox1.Items.Add(drd.GetString(0).ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }

        connection.Close();
    }

    private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=email_client;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from address_book where name='" + checkedListBox1.Text + "'", con);
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            textBox1.Text += Convert.ToString(dr["id"] + ",");
        }
        dr.Close();
    }

    private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
        tt.SetToolTip(textBox1, "sorry");
    }
}
```

Comment: ok sir i will follow this editing rules.....but for now can you plz give me the perfect answer...@ pravprab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should not use `SelectedIndexChanged` event if you'd like to show "checked" items. Use `ItemCheck` instead:

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
```

Then use `CheckedListBox.CheckedItems` to retrive all items which are checked:

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=email_client;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("select * from address_book where name='{0}'", item), con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(Convert.ToString(dr["id"] + ","));
        }
        dr.Close();
    }

    textBox1.Text = stringBuilder.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
}
```

Remember use `string.TrimEnd()` to trim the last comma.

Well, this is not the most effective way to do this, because you need to go through each checked item when one of them changed. You could use a `Dictionary` to maintain name-id pairs -- at least it is no need to execute SQL queries when you unchecked an item, right? :)

Comment: thank you sir......you give me a perfect code ........but using SelectedIndexChanged rather than ItemCheck gives me the exact solution......

Comment: `SelectedIndexChanged` will be called when you select an item, that means, when you focus on the item without checking it (click it at its content, not the checkbox). And `ItemCheck` will be called only when an item is checked or unchecked. In your question, it is said that "When I *Checked* item in the checkedListBox it shows the value of the respective item in the TextBox". I think `SelectedIndexChanged` is what you need, not `SelectedIndexChanged`.

Comment: Hope I didn't misunderstand your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

To remove ,

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, textBox1.Text.Length - 1);
```

But I would ideally keep my dr["id"] in a List and create a small function that iterates through the list and return comma separated string. Adding and Removing items should take place in that collection.

Comment: sir actually i am not clear with solution can u plz provide me a certain sort of coding for the the above mention problem